# Limit text-width in LyX without fullscreen?

Tags: lyx

Using LyX, in *Tools → Preferences → Editing → Control* there is an option to limit the displayed text width in full-screen mode, meant to avoid hard-to-read overly long lines.

Is there some similar feature for limiting the text width *without* fullscreen mode?

Right now I sometimes have to switch between fullscreen and windowed, and having the text suddenly expand from a convenient line width to full widescreen width is distracting.

While it is possible to just reduce the window size, this often ends up hiding certain GUI elements, such as labels of long equations. Furthermore, it doesn't easily provide consistent line-width between fullscreen and windowed mode, which would help by preventing the visual distraction of line breaks shifting around in the transition.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible in LyX. There is a pending feature request [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9376).